# Azure B2C Having multiple identity provider but doesn't show in the sign in page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure AD B2C, I know you can add multiple Identity providers. and on the Sign In page will show those IDPs like the following picture. But I have about 10 identity provider and doesn't look good to show 10 IDPs on the page. is there a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make them(those IDPs) into click events for an html pull-down list.If you are using user flow,you can customize the UI.
In your Ad tenant,find your storage account->container->create a new container and upload your .css and .html file.
[image]
[image]

And this is a simple pull-down list example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<STYLE type=text/css>
body { font-family: arial, ̎ͥ, serif; font-size:12px; padding:10px }
#nav { line-height: 24px; list-style-type: none; background:#666; }
#nav a { display: block; width: 180px; text-align:center; }
#nav a:link { color:#666; text-decoration:none; }
#nav a:visited { color:#666;text-decoration:none; }
#nav a:hover { color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold; }
#nav li { float: left; width: 180px; background:#CCC; }
#nav li a:hover{ background:#999; }
#nav li ul { line-height: 27px; list-style-type: none;text-align:left; visibility : hidden; width: 180px; position: absolute; padding: 5px}
#nav li ul li{ float: left; width: 180px; background: #F6F6F6; } 
#nav li ul a{ display: block; width: 180px;width: 156px;text-align:left;padding-left:24px; } 
#nav li ul a:hover { color:#F3F3F3;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal; background:#C00; } 
#nav li:hover ul { visibility : visible; }
</STYLE> 
</head>
 
<body>
<UL id=nav> 
<LI><A href="#">sign with your social account</A> 
<UL> 
<LI><A href="#">facebook</A></LI> 
<LI><A href="#">microsoft</A></LI> 
<LI><A href="#">salesforce</A></LI> 
</UL></LI> 
</body>
</html>
```